# How do I force prompts to display on my primary monitor in Windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows, multiple-monitors

Every time there's a prompt of some kind, or a dialog box, it's displayed on my secondary monitor. Here's an example.

1. <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (Run prompt displays on secondary)
2. `notepad` and <kbd>Enter</kbd> (Notepad.exe displays on primary)
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> (Save as dialog displays on secondary)

Why is it behaving like this, and is there a way to force all new prompts, dialog boxes, program windows, etc. to display on my primary monitor?

> Honestly, I thought that's what the option "make this my main display" was for?!?...

Would it not be more intelligent if the program windows were displayed on the secondary monitor? In the example above, have the Run prompt and Save as dialog displayed on primary, and then pop that Notepad.exe window on the secondary monitor?

What controls this anyway? I know that Windows can remember the last location on the monitor where you had a certain program window, and then when you open that same window again, it would be displayed in same location. So I tried to open the Run prompt, move it over to my primary monitor, open a notepad from it, close everything down, and open the Run prompt again. It displayed on the secondary monitor again........

Comment: Just to avoid any confusion. Your primary display is the one with taskbar. Is this correct? And popups/dialogues are appearing on the other display (the one without taskbar). Is this what you are saying?

Comment: @smc Yes, the one with the taskbar is in front of me. I have two monitors. The secondary monitor is on my left. I am using the extended desktop mode. FWIW, the monitor in front of me is identified as number 2 in Screen Resolution (control panel). But I have selected it and checked "make this my main display"?!...

Comment: Have you used standard windows interface to set up your multiple displays? Or have you used software specific to your Graphic Adapter?

Comment: I tried disconnecting them now, and then reconnecting each as a single monitor. The "primary" is connected with VGA, and the secondary with DVI. If I only connect one of them, it's identified as number 1. And if I connect VGA first, and then DVI, or DVI first, and then VGA, it doesn't matter. The VGA (primary) is always identified as number 2 and DVI as number 1. So whichever is connected with DVI takes precedence over VGA? I know it's better to use DVI, but what the hell... need to lift and move monitors around to get the results you want?? Ridiculous!

Comment: @smc It's all Windows settings (control panel, screen resolution). Would it help to use Catalyst Control Center instead? I have it installed as this is an AMD A10 APU system, so it's inevitable not to have the AMD software installed (chipset and gpu).

Comment: I mean the Windows settings do make the "2" (VGA) monitor my primary, by making my taskbar appear there, instead of on "1" (DVI). But I just don't understand why I have to move my eyes left and right when prompt and dialogs start coming up. Program windows display on the primary monitor (as selected in Windows settings), but the dialogs and prompts don't... I don't get it... can't move those from "1" or what?

Comment: This is not a normal behavior. I have the setup similar to yours and in my case all new popups and dialog boxes always appear on _primary_ display. Program windows remember their position and will reappear exactly where they were before closing. I assume this is the behavior you are trying to achieve. I recommend you to try AMD CCC, and see if this makes any difference. In my case I am using Intel Graphic and Media Control Center, because I am not satisfied with windows built-in tools. Let me know if using CCC software helps

Comment: Also, I don't think that numbering of monitors has any impact on this. It really should not. Its the primary monitor setting that should matter. In my case primary monitor is number 2. And I don't get any problems

Comment: @smc Not all systems are made equal. You are on Intel platform, right? I am on AMD. And you are using Intel software to make these changes, right? And I am using Windows own settings for this (haven't tried CCC, don't see any valid reason why I should use that instead for something basic as this, Windows own settings should suffice). And yes, I have seen this behavior on Intel systems as well. This is all Windows related I believe... and the numbers do seem to have a deeper meaning than just for identification purposes. Like type of interface/connection.

Comment: @smc Your primary monitor is a "2". But what is your interface? Is it VGA, DVI, HDMI, DP?...

Comment: Its VGA. Anyway, I am glad you resolved your problem

Comment: @smc Hmh... that's a surprise. Then it might be that the Intel software is doing a better job at this than the Windows native settings do.

Comment: I will not start praising Intel software here. But as I have already mentioned I have had problems with Primary/Secondary settings before and I resolved it all by switching to OEMs control center. This is why I recommended it here

Comment: @smc Just had the monitors moved back to original location, undone all changes, started all over, used AMD CCC software to make the "2" (VGA) the primary. Sure, it made the taskbar appear on it, but just like when using Windows own settings the prompts and dialogs were still stuck at "1" for whatever the reason. So it made no difference using the CCC software. Perhaps Intel software is in fact better, after all. LOL! :)

Comment: Nah... that ain't it... this is something else... something from another world, another planet. Let's just call it a bug. So numbers do matter. I believe even the AMD CCC software is reading the settings from Windows, it's not like it has its own mind or something. It's just another way to interact with these settings, another UI. I'll just have to move my monitors around once more, and be happy with it. It's a good physical exercise here at office. Just another day in the Windows world.

Answer (score 3):

Try restoring the window, to it's normal size, then move it to the primary monitor.  Then x out (shut down).  Now Windows should remember where it last was.  Then if you re-open it, then you can choose to maximize it and shut down again.  Then it will re-open on the primary in a maximized window.

This worked for me when I noticed Adobe kept opening on my secondary monitor and I started looking for solutions online.

Comment: This doesn’t seem to work for (Win)+(R) — although it’s not clear whether this was ever really a problem.  It does seem to work for application windows.

Comment: I am unable to test this at the moment. But thanks for sharing your findings.

Answer (score 1):

Yup, the "make this my main display" in Windows can't move prompts and dialog boxes over to the monitor you select. It is only able to move the taskbar and program windows over to that monitor. To see all program windows on that monitor, you might need to close the program windows first, then reopen them.

So here's what I did:

- Lifted my "primary" (i.e. "2", i.e. VGA) monitor and put it on the
  left.
- Lifted my "secondary" (i.e. "1", i.e. DVI) monitor and put it on the
  right.
- In Screen Resolution (Control Panel), selected "1" and ticked "make
  this my main display".

So now, both program windows and prompts and dialogs display on the monitor in front of me.

1. <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (Run prompt displays on **primary** (DVI))
2. `notepad` and <kbd>Enter</kbd> (Notepad.exe displays on **primary** (DVI))
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> (Save as dialog displays on **primary** (DVI))

Voilà! Set and done!

Comment: This is ambiguous. What exactly did you do to resolve your issue? The description you have provided seems like an ordinary setup. I assumed that you had it initially.

Comment: Ambiguous? Which part? You want me to add a before/after for comparison?

Comment: I believe it would be useful for anyone with similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue,but for the windows command prompt.
I had a secondary monitor which I use it for my development VM, So whenever I open my command prompt on my primary monitor, the window use to goto the secondary monitor, and the hard thing is when you are disconnected from the secondary monitor the cmd window is still not displayed in the primary monitor, but it will be virtually displayed to the secondary monitor, and you can only see that in the task bar of the primary monitor.

solution:

open the command prompt and right-click on that window, make the winodw-position values {left, top} to zero.
now close the prompt and open again, it will open in the primary window always even if the secondary monitor is connected.!!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, and the OP likely is well past this issue by now, but in case anyone else comes across this, I'll add my two cents. IME, Windows does a poor job with multi displays in general, and an especially poor job with a secondary monitor being positioned to the left of the primary monitor. For this reason, even if I have a secondary monitor physically to the left of my primary monitor (e.g. currently my TV is to the left of and further back from my monitor), in Windows I have it set to the right, so I go off-screen to the right on the monitor and come on-screen on the left of the display left of it. Certainly not intuitive, but it prevents all sorts of other issues. I suspect in the OP's case, Windows is simply using the left-most display as "primary" instead of the actual primary display because, well, Windows. So if anyone else is having this problem with a similar setup, I'd suggest trying to switch the displays' positions relative to each other in Windows' settings and see if that makes a difference and, if it does, consider rearranging them physically if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I had this issue as well, UAC prompt positions got messed up with some apps and only display on the 2nd screen which happens to be my tv, anyway I managed to fix it, what you need to do is drag the UAC Prompt to your Primary Monitor and click show more details on the prompt then click change when these notifications appear, another UAC window will open up with a vertical bar with 4 different settings, just drag the bar setting down and then back up to it's original setting position then click ok, this will re trigger UAC's screen position to your primary monitor. hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Late post but hope it helps somebody...

I want my CMD windows to pop up on my secondary window (right) where also I dragged the TaskBar.
Left is my Primary selected screen in Windows settings for gaming.
I dont want CMD's Windows to popup behind a game...

My Fix:
1] I opened a CMD (Window+R key) window and clicked the icon top left on the window bar.

2] On the menu I clicked Defaults.

3] Clicked layout tab.

4] In the Frame: Window Position I did the following:
LEFT:

- I Added to the SCREEN resolution WIDTH of the LEFT (gaming) screen to the Half Of the SCREEN resolution WIDTH of the Right screen. This is now Center RIGHT Screen.
- Devided the ESTIMATED Width of the CMD window by two and subtracted that of the Value above.

TOP:

- I Subtracted the half of the ESTMATED CMD Window Height from the RIGHT SCREEN SCREEN HEIGHT.

Removed the "Let System Position Window" Bit and voi'la !

WIDTH FOR ME:
So for me that was 1920+(1920/2) = Center Right = 2880
I estimated the CMD Window size to be 900 and the factor is 900/2 =450
Center 2880 - Right portion of CMD window 450 = 2430

TOP FOR ME:
Height right Screen 1080 / 2 = 540 Center Right Screen
Height CMD window estimate 480 pixels. For center = 480 / 2 = 240 Pixels.
540 - 240 = 300

Hope it Helps ;)

ps.: English is not my default language, please correct as necessary but restrain the smart comments ;) Thanks !